# Mongoose find and save, want to send the message of the error as res.json

Tags: mongoose, find, save

I'm setting up a new api, using a mvc pattern. And I have a problem with sending the right response to the user.

I'm updating my obj and I'm doing in 2 steps in order to take advantage of mongoose validation.

The update function is def in a repository module:

```
const update = (id, newBook) => {
  return Book.findById({_id: id}, (err, oldBook) => {
    oldBook.title = newBook.title;

    oldBook.save().catch(err => {throw new Error(err)});
  })
    .exec()
    .catch(err => err);
};
```

and my controller module:

```
exports.update = async (req, res) => {
  const requestBody = req.body;
  let book = await BookRepository.update(req.params.book_id, requestBody);

  if (book instanceof Error) {
    res.json(new Response(false, [], book));
  } else {
    res.json(new Response(true));
  }
};
```

If I do as I presented above, I cannot catch the error and send the Response.

Comment: Throw the `err` instead of catching it in your `update` function.

Comment: I've tried your advice, but the app crashes, bcz the error is not catched

Answer (score 0):

Throw the `err` instead of catching it in your update function, then catch it in your controller.

**Using a promise**

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  const requestBody = req.body;
  BookRepository.update(req.params.book_id, requestBody)
     .exec()
     .then(doc => res.json(doc))
     .catch(err => res.json(err))
```